# How to curl payload with PHP to python api?

Tags: python, php, api, curl

Im new to PHP trying to figure out how to post an API-Call with data to one of my Endpoints written in Python.

My Endpoint expects a payload which I load into a dictionary with the request module. After that I just access the payload dictionary and process the data. I just don't know how to correctly post the data in PHP so I can use request.json to parse it in a dictionary.

The Question here hasn't been answered and is not as that well explained:
[how to send Request Payload with php cURL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31950691/how-to-send-request-payload-with-php-curl)

This Question has been answered but I don't know how that translates into PHP cURL:
[How do I POST JSON data with cURL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7172784/how-do-i-post-json-data-with-curl)

My Python endpoint:

```
@application.route('/generate', methods=['POST'])
def generate():
    messageBody = {}
    headers = request.headers
    payload = request.json

    try:
        auth = headers.get("X-Api-Key")
        if token(auth):
            credentials = credentialsFunc(auth)

            try:
                processed= gen(payload['type'], payload['quantity'], payload['location'])
```

How do I post the relevant data to a Python endpoint?
My curl in PHP so far:

```
$data = json_encode(array(
                "location" => $country,
                "type" => $type,
                "quantity" => $quantity
            ));

$ch = curl_init();
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, getenv('REDIRECT_GENERATION_URL'));
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

            $headers = array();
            $headers[] = 'X-Api-Key: ' . $key;
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);     <--My endpoint can't parse the data
            echo $data;

            $result = curl_exec($ch);
            if (curl_errno($ch)) {
                echo 'Error:' . curl_error($ch);
            }

            $res = json_decode( $result, true );
            echo $res['balance']
            curl_close($ch);
```

How do I send a PHP POST-Request so my Python endpoint can parse it with request.json?

Comment: _“but I don't know how that translates into PHP cURL”_ - https://incarnate.github.io/curl-to-php/ exists.

Comment: According to your link `json_encode` does exactly the same.

Comment: Agreed, a Content-type header with application/json would probably help a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `json_encode` inside PHP was actually the correct way to prepare a JSON to use with CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS. Turns out my Endpoint had some version problem with a Python module I was using.

If Google brings you here and you wonder how you can send a payload with PHP, then this is the way:

```
$data = json_encode(array(
          "location" => $country,
          "type" => $type,
          "quantity" => $quantity
        ));

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, getenv('REDIRECT_GENERATION_URL'));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

$headers = array();
$headers[] = 'X-Api-Key: ' . $key;
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);    

$result = curl_exec($ch);
if (curl_errno($ch)) {
   echo 'Error:' . curl_error($ch);
   }

$res = json_decode( $result, true );
print_r($res);
curl_close($ch);
```